# Cannot get XDate to work with React-Native (.toLocaleString)

Tags: javascript, react-native

On a react-native project, I want to display **a DateTime variable in the user's locale format.** Other posts suggested the use of the library XDate because **.toLocaleString** is not available in React-Native. However, I could not get it to work.

```
import XDate from 'xdate';
....
handleDatePicked = (dateTime) => {
    console.log("Before formatting: ", dateTime);
    let d = new XDate(dateTime);
    console.log("after XDate: ", d);
    console.log("US format: ", d.toLocaleString("en-US"));
    console.log("AU format: ", d.toLocaleString("en-AU"));
    console.log("Date AU format: ", d.toLocaleDateString('en-AU', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
    console.log("Date & Time string: ", d.toString('dd/MM/yyyy h(:mm) TT') );
.... 
};
```

**Results (console):**

Before formatting:  2019-07-22T22:15:00.000Z

after XDate:  "2019-07-22T22:15:00.000Z"

US format:  Tue Jul 23 08:15:00 2019

AU format:  Tue Jul 23 08:15:00 2019

Date AU format:  07/23/19

Date & Time string:  23/07/2019 8:15 AM

**Expected Results:**

I expected the US and AU formats (above) to be different from each other. What am I missing?

**Edit:**

I added statements for the methods .toLocaleDateString and .toString. It seems that .toLocal* methods do NOT accept the specified locale, e.g. "en-AU". These methods seem to use the device's locale, instead of the locale, which is specified in their parameters!

Is this how they are supposed to behave? If yes, is there any other way of enforcing a specific locale?

Answer (score 0):

xdate (at least version 0.8.2) don't provide/polyfill locales, you simple use wrong library.
May be moment or date-fns will satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the input. On the following page, it says that it does. Am I looking at the wrong page? https://arshaw.com/xdate/

Comment: @BilalAbdeen See code: https://github.com/arshaw/xdate/blob/v0.8.2/src/xdate.js#L636, here it simple proxy toLocaleString to Date.prototype.toLocaleString :-)